# Eek! "You have failed too many recent review audits" formatting is not consistent

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, error-message

Yesterday I fail a review and after it I am banned for review for two days. When I click on [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) link I got audit fail error in large and bold format like following,

> [image]

But when I click on other audit by writing url in browser ( for e.g. [Late Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) ) then I saw same error message with different fonts style, like below,

> [image]

I believe these error message should be look same in all the audit review section.

Comment: Not related to your question, but impersonation is bad.  You should consider changing your profile picture.

Comment: @devnull This is [Lord Shiva](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Lord+Shiva&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=iFoQU6GcKsyFrQf4lYGQAg&ved=0CDoQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=647) for your general knowledge.

Comment: Had it been a graphic of Lord Shiva, it would have been ok.  But seem to have used the picture of a living human.

Comment: @devnull thats because it is from tele seria [devo ke dev mahadev](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Lord+Shiva&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=iFoQU6GcKsyFrQf4lYGQAg&ved=0CDoQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=647#q=devon+ke+dev+mahadev&spell=1&tbm=isch)

Comment: @devnull assuming the picture is in the public domain it's ok. Its only using pictures not in the public domain or using both the display name and picture to create the impression of being someone else thats not ok

Comment: @devnull: and I suppose you're really a clownfish? Who's 94 years old. Despite being a filesystem construct on an OS that's not even 50 yet.

Comment: @rahil: how is this a dupe? This is a bug report...